# Repairing Grub2

Tags: grub2, reinstall

We are having a Hell of a time trying to boot up. Read all kinds of materials on re-installing Grub2 but each one presumes that we already know where Grub2 is located and/or that there is only one ext4 partition on our disk. Some say that Grub2 is on the partition where Ubuntu is installed but, since we formatted the drive and installed Ubuntu 17, they are all partitions  where Ubuntu is located. Incredibly simple but, so far, not one of the 'helpers' has figured that out. I am 40  years out from the last programming I have done and really don't care to re-learn everything I have forgotten. One mentioned Grub2 is on the 'Linux' partition but, again, they are all Linux, and one said that it is an '83,' and as you can plainly see, two '83's. As well, sda5 is encrypted, so not sure how that affects possibly fixes. We have the password, of course.

As big a pain in the keister as Ubuntu has been so far, we really hate the very idea of using that spybot Windows, again.

Thank You, again, for your assistance.

After using Boot-Repair
Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jTMR6n9tCZ/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

results of sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x558fe20e

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1499135   1497088   731M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1501182 625141759 623640578 297.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1501184 625141759 623640576 297.4G 83 Linux
```

Results of GParted

```
                Size        Used        Unused  Flags
dev/sda1    ext4        731.00 MiB  233.40      497.60  boot
dev/sda2    extended    297.38 GiB     ---
 dev/sda5   [Encrypted] 297.38 GiB  297.38 GiB    0.00
```

---

We apologize. I swear I answered your concerns two days ago, but it is not  posted, so here they are:

```
I apologize for not including Ubuntu 17.10. There were/are only two devices
```

with operating systems attached to this computer: the broken Ubuntu 17 system
we are trying to repair, and the liveUSB Ubuntu 17.10 we are using to talk to
you. The rest are all storage/back-up only. We have the standard Ubuntu 17
installation which we have confirmed is GPT.

@oldfred: We have disconnect all other drives and run boot-repair, but have  been unable to access the encrypted partition. Mount in Gparted is grayed out,   and mount is not offered in Disks.

We have tried to mount the encrypted partition using:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cryptsetup --type luks open /dev/sda5 encrypted
Device /dev/sda5 doesn't exist or access denied.

{https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/how-to-mount-luks-encrypted-partitions-manually/}

and

cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2/ crypthome
Device /dev/sda5/ doesn't exist or access denied.

{https://linuxconfig.org/basic-guide-to-encrypting-linux-partitions-with-luks}

Comment: `grub` doesn't sit in just one location. Grub stage1 is located in the MBR (master boot record) or first sector of the drive (regardless of how many partitions the drive has; ie. there is only  one MBR per drive).  Later stages of grub (1.5, 2) reside in /boot which can be its own partition, or in your / partition.  You can have many /boot partitions (one for each installed Ubuntu, GNU/Linux etc), but the only one that runs is the one pointed to by the MBR which is usually the last installed.  If you have multiple drives, your BIOS will determine which MBR is used.

Comment: My guess is the important part of grub you need is on sda1 (which possibly is /boot).  Questions about grub usually ignore the MBR as its location is always known and the user dictates which MBR is used where multiple drives using machine bios/eufi (the boot-repair link indicates multiple drives). You didn't include many details such as the version (&/or flavor) of Ubuntu, nor provide details in your post about your other drives or windoze.  It's possible that the grub is perfectly fine, but you need to tell your system to use it (which is machine specific setting via eufi/bios)

Comment: Looks like you have an MBR disk and not the more modern GPT setup. Under those circumstances grub normally resides in the MBR. You haven't said exactly what boot-up problem you're having, nor have you mentioned whether another OS co-exists with Ubuntu. That pasted boot-repair link has nothing to do with your set-up?? Or did someone else edit that in? Your gparted data just shows there is one disk and one OS - right?

Comment: Disconnect all your other drives, and run Boot-Repair but manually mount the encrypted partitions before running fixes. I do prefer gpt as it has backup partition table, but converting back and forth creates issues. Either stay with MBR(msdos) or convert all drives to gpt and then only use gpt. The only reason for MBR anymore is if you want to boot Windows in BIOS mode as then MBR is requried.